# django forms no inserta data

Tags: mysql, django, django-forms, crud

tengo un formulario con un modelo relacionado con varios modelos, cree el formulario y se muestra bien, pero al darle submit no pasa nada, es decir no se guardan los datos en la db, uso python 3.7, django 2.0 y mysql:

Modelo

```html
class Proyecto(models.Model):
    id_proyecto = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    numero_proyecto = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    descripcion_proyecto = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    os_moebius = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    id_solicitante = models.ForeignKey('Solicitante', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_solicitante', blank=True, null=True)
    id_responsable = models.ForeignKey(Lider, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_responsable', blank=True, null=True)
    id_nodo = models.ForeignKey(Nodo, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_nodo', blank=True, null=True)
    id_ep = models.ForeignKey(EstadoProyecto, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_EP', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_tp = models.ForeignKey('TipoProyecto', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_TP', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_sm = models.ForeignKey('ServiceManager', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_SM', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    id_herramienta = models.ForeignKey(Herramienta, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_herramienta', blank=True, null=True)
    id_cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_cliente', blank=True, null=True)
    observaciones = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    id_agente = models.ForeignKey(Agente, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_agente', blank=True, null=True)
    nombre_tarea = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    periodicidad = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    hora_ejecucion = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    tiempo_ejecucion_manual = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    tiempo_ejecucion_automatico = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.descripcion_proyecto
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'proyecto'
        ordering = ('-numero_proyecto', )
```

vista:

```html
class ProyectoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Proyecto
    fields = ['numero_proyecto',
            'descripcion_proyecto',
            'os_moebius',
            'id_solicitante',
            'id_responsable',
            'id_nodo',
            'id_ep',
            'id_tp',
            'id_sm',
            'id_herramienta',
            'id_cliente',
            'observaciones',
            'id_agente',
            'nombre_tarea',
            'periodicidad',
            'hora_ejecucion',
            'tiempo_ejecucion_manual',
            'tiempo_ejecucion_automatico']
```

Url:

```html
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$',views.index , name='index'),
     url(r'^details/(?P<id>\w{0,50})/$', views.details),
     url(r'projects/add/$', views.ProyectoCreate.as_view(), name="project-add")
]
```

proyecto_form.html

```html
{% extends 'projects/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container center-align" style="width:35%">
        <div class="row section">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
                    <div class="card-content white-text">
                        <span class="card-title">Nuevo Proyecto</span><br><br>
                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% for fields in form %}
                                        <span class="red-text">{{ fields.error }}</span>
                                        <label>{{ fields.numero_proyecto }}</label>
                                        <div>{{ fields }}</div>
                                {% endfor %}
                                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
                            </form>
                    </div>                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberías encapsular tu "vista" en la carpeta "forms", que es donde se definen los formularios, y en "vista" o view es donde se van a recoger esos campos a través de método POST.

Ahí es donde se debe hacer el save() que guardará los datos en la base de datos. No tengo demasiada experiencia en django pero creo que tu fallo es que no estás tratando los datos en la view, si no que has generado el form.

Recuerda que los formularios tienen su lugar especifico en la carpeta form. Espero que esto te sirva de guía. 
La view sería algo así:

```
def post(self, request):
   proyecto_form = ProyectoForm(request.POST)
       if proyecto_form.is_valid():
           proyecto = Proyecto(proyecto_form['numero_proyecto'], 
                            proyecto_form['descripcion_proyecto']....) 
           proyecto.save()
       return render(request, 'aquí el .html hacia donde quieras 
                     redirigir', context={"proyecto": proyecto})
```